# gwtupload : java.lang.RuntimeException: The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file

Tags: gwt, gwtupload

I developed multiple file upload in GWT using `gwtupload` plugin. It works fine in debug mode. I created `war` and started in `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`. If I upload one file its working fine but when I select other file for upload its throwing and error.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.` Here is my server log. Now how to resolve this error?

```
16:22:52,147 INFO  [gwtupload.server.UploadListener] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-6) UploadListener  created new instance. (slow=200, requestSize=4672140)
16:22:59,361 SEVERE [gwtupload.server.UploadServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-4) UPLOAD-SERVLET (pB19zxemUC3i-3tAQt5G+SzE.undefined) The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.
16:22:59,549 INFO  [gwtupload.server.UploadListener] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-6) UploadListener pB19zxemUC3i-3tAQt5G+SzE.undefined The upload has been canceled after 139137 bytes received, raising an exception (RuntimeException) to close the socket
16:22:59,690 SEVERE [gwtupload.server.UploadServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-6) UPLOAD-SERVLET (pB19zxemUC3i-3tAQt5G+SzE.undefined) Unexpected Exception -> The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.
    at gwtupload.server.UploadAction.doPost(UploadAction.java:200)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.nextenders.server.ExceptionHandler.doFilter(ExceptionHandler.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

16:22:59,713 INFO  [gwtupload.server.UploadServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-6) Unknown Exception when receiving a file.: gwtupload.server.exceptions.UploadException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.
    at gwtupload.server.UploadServlet.parsePostRequest(UploadServlet.java:985) [gwtupload-custom.jar:]
    at gwtupload.server.UploadAction.doPost(UploadAction.java:178) [gwtupload-custom.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.nextenders.server.ExceptionHandler.doFilter(ExceptionHandler.java:28) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The request has been rejected because the server is already receiving another file.
    at gwtupload.server.UploadAction.doPost(UploadAction.java:200) [gwtupload-custom.jar:]
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When this happens is because the previous listener used in the servlet has not been removed from memory. Normally this can happen if you have multiple tab instances in your browser, or if you reload your app while a file is being uploaded. Wait for a while, and try again.

I've never used jboss in my projects, so could be an issue in its servlet container, although it uses tomcat which works well with gwtupload.

If you can isolate the issue in a simple project which can reproduce the issue always, post it so as I can take a look and debug.

Comment: I don't know why right now this problem is also solved. After commenting `removeItem(request, item.getFieldName());` line. As I said in other thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248675/servlet-receives-0bytes-of-file). BTW thanks for the help