# Servlet receives 0Bytes of file

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwtupload

I'm working on multiple file upload. Having strange issue when uploading multiple files.

**Case**: When I select multiple files, if one of file size is big compare to other its not submitted to servlet. I'm selecting below files(Image). I used breakpoint and went to step by step and found that `error.txt`'s size is `0Bytes` in servlet. If I upload this by selecting as single its uploading properly.

> Having same issue with other file when its big, its not specific to error.txt. I just gave you the case

[image]

**FYI**: I'm using `gwtupload` plugin for multiple upload. Here is the link of project : https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload

---

**Update:**

@Manolo Why you used `cont` variable in servlet?

```
 int cont = 0;
 for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
    if (false == item.isFormField()) {
       cont ++;
```

Comment: which version of gwtupload are you using?

Comment: I tried `gwtupload-0.6.6.jar` and `gwtupload-0.6.7-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: So it happens in gwtupload when you enable multiple (which is an experimental feature), or it happens always using MultiUplader ?

Comment: I used `MultiUplader` in several pages and facing same issue everywhere.

Comment: I used 3 - 4 `MultiUploader` in same page. Does it causing the issue?

Comment: It should not cause any problem, when you have multiple uploaders, they share the queue and dont send any file until the previous one has been sent. In server side only a file can be received at the same time, so as we can track progress. Please setup an example project and post it so as I can take a look. BTW the gwtupload [samples](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/gwtuploadsample.MultipleUploadSample/MultipleUploadSample.html) project has multiple uploaders in the same page and they work fine.

Comment: @Manolo I added something in question. Why you used `cont` variable in servlet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38846/discussion-between-vicky-thakor-and-manolo)

Answer (score 0):

After tons of try I found the solution so let me show you where I made mistake in code.

```
for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
      if (false == item.isFormField()) {
        try {
          /// Create a temporary file placed in the default system temp folder
          File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin");
          item.write(file);

          /// Save a list with the received files
          receivedFiles.put(item.getFieldName(), file);
          receivedContentTypes.put(item.getFieldName(), item.getContentType());

          /// Send a customized message to the client.
          response += "File saved as " + file.getAbsolutePath();

          // Below line is creating the problem.
          removeItem(request, item.getFieldName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new UploadActionException(e);
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm removing each file using `removeItem(request, item.getFieldName());` after processing it. Somehow its removing the `error.txt` file. I don't know why. But after removing that line. It worked for me.

Comment: That is obvious, you are adding items to the receivedFiles hash-table, and at the same time you remove them running the `removeItem`, so at the end you dont have any file saved. You just have to run the `removeSessionFileItems(request);` after the for loop to remove session files for the next upload.

Comment: @Manolo Thanks for all your support. I also write blog. Its www.javaquery.com . I'll definitely write about your plugin.